# Running a Screen instance of a program as non-root

Tags: screen, cron, su

I've got a dedicated server (Ubuntu 12.04, no GUI) set up to launch an instance of McMyAdmin and attach it to a screen instance every time I reboot the hardware. I have the command saved to root's crontab as:

```
@reboot cd /var/MC_SVR && screen -dmS McMyAdmin ./MCMA2_Linux_x86_64
```

Problem being, though, I have a user set up specifically for FTP access to the server files so I don't always have to SSH into the machine. Since the server is being started as a root process, all the files it makes are, obviously, set with root as the owner.

So I chown'd all the files and set them to `ftpuser`. Now I'm stuck with trying to get the process to start as ftpuser. I've tried doing the following but to no avail:

```
cd /var/MC_SVR && su ftpuser - -c 'screen -dmS McMyAdmin ./MCMA2_Linux_x86_64'
```

I try this in terminal and I get no errors or anything (in fact I never get anything unless it's a syntax error from su), but there's no screen instance to access and so I can assume the server never starts.

So, what am I doing wrong? Or am I just not accessing the screen instance correctly since it's (supposed) to be launched by another user?

Comment: Thank you for confirming that, I converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common problems with cron is that it runs with a minimal shell and minimal environmental variables. Because of this it is best to always use the full path to programs, binaries, libs, or files.

In addition, although you can use su, sudo is, IMO, a better tool. Specify the user with the -u flag.

So, putting it altogether,

```
sudo -u ftpuser "screen -dmS /var/MC_SVR/McMyAdmin /var/MC_SVR/MCMA2_Linux_x86_64"
```